# Elastic Beanstalk - Ebextension config file not showing on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/vhost.conf":
    mode: "000777"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      NameVirtualHost *:80

      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.domain.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/app/current/api/"
        <Directory "/var/app/current/api">
          AllowOverride All
          Require all Granted
        </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>

container_commands:
  00_chmod:
    command: "sudo chmod 777 /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk"
  01_rewrite:
    command: "sudo mv -f /home/ec2-user/vhost.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/vhost.conf"
  02_apache:
    command: "sudo apachectl restart"
```

This is the config i am using, i got it looking for solutions to my issue, now ino there is questions to this but the asnwers are outdated and don;t work, the config runs correctly i can confirm in the logs that the command are been ran with no error, but when i ssh into the ec2 there is no conf file in the directory, i assuming eb is removing them after deployment.

anyone any idea whats going on ? the aws docs are next to useless.

Comment: "there is no conf file in the directory" - which file? Which directory?

Comment: within /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk in the ec2 instance, I ssh in and verified that the conf isnt their.

command: "sudo mv -f /home/ec2-user/vhost.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/vhost.conf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes to http must be done using `.platform/httpd/conf.d`, not regular `.ebextentions`. The details and examples are in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) under "Configuring Apache HTTPD":

> To extend the Elastic Beanstalk default Apache configuration, add .conf configuration files to a folder named **.platform/httpd/conf.d** in your application source bundle.

Comment: okay, so ideally, i have this in the wrong place, i should in-fact create a directory in my bundle to be .platform->httpd->conf.d->myfile.config ? 

having trouble finding reference to "Configuring Apache HTTPD" on the aws docs linked.

Comment: @alexmalcolm Its under "Reverse proxy configuration".

Comment: ahh okay got it no worries, sorry, aws doc is vast so i command + f the title.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the right directions, I voted this the answer, hopefully now anyone looking at this wont be mislead with outdated answers pointing to ebextension.